# Why isn't the value updated when publishing to a Redis channel?

Tags: python, redis, fastapi

I'm trying to use Redis in my `FastAPI` -application and struggling to update a value when publishing to a channel.

This is my Redis client setup:

```
import logging

import redis as _redis

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

REDIS_URL = "redis://redis:6379"

class RedisClient:
    __instance = None
    client: _redis.Redis

    def __new__(cls) -> "RedisClient":
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = object.__new__(cls)

            try:
                logger.info("Connecting to Redis")
                client = _redis.Redis.from_url(REDIS_URL)
                cls.client = client

            except Exception:
                logger.error("Unable to connect to Redis")

            logger.info("Connected to Redis")

        return cls.__instance

    def disconnect(self):
        logger.info("Closing Redis connection")
        self.client.connection_pool.disconnect()


redis = RedisClient().client
redis_pubsub = redis.pubsub()
```

This is my `POST` route what I'm using to test updating the value:

```
@router.post("/", response_model=Any)
async def post(tracing_no: int) -> Any:
    data = {"tracing_no": tracing_no, "result": 200, "client_id": "10"}
    data = json.dumps(data)
    result = redis.publish(TestChannel.TestTopic.value, data)
    return redis.get(TestChannel.TestTopic.value)
```

This code returns always `"{\"tracing_no\": 5, \"result\": 200, \"client_id\": \"10\"}"`, no matter what number I give as `tracking_no` when I send the request. I think `5` was the first number I used when testing and that is in my `dump.rdb` -file.
Any ideas why my `tracking_no` isn't updating?

Comment: You're using `get` to retrieve a value, but you're using `publish` to publish a value - you're not setting it. Did you intend to use pubsub, eller did you intend to use the regular key/value-store?

Comment: @MatsLindh My intention is to use pubsub as eventually I'm planning to setup websockets and subscribe to a Redis channel to listen to any changes. But for now, I'd just like to make this demo route to work. So, how could I return the updated value if I've set it with `publish`?

Comment: "publish" does not set anything, it publishes a message on a channel. If nobody is listening for the message, it disappears; messages are not durable - so if there is no subscribers, there are no-one to use that message. If you just want to "publish" a value, use `set` - that stores a value in the key/value store for future consumption. If you want durable streams that someone can begin listening to at an arbitrary point in time and get previous messages published as well, you want Redis Streams, not pubsub.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for your advice, tested and it worked. If you want to transform your comment to an answer, I'll accept it as a solution. I'll have to figure out later if I want you use publish or set, but for now, this solves my problem.